# Ubuntu 18.04 - bad d-i Packages file from local mirror

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mirror, ubuntu-18.04, ipxe

I am trying to PXE install Ubuntu 18.04 from a local mirror. When I get to the select mirror part of the install, it says failed to download a file (see link for pictures) and also bad d-i Packages file. The PXE client is a Virtualbox VM.

https://imgur.com/a/1Bsvq8c

I have done the following:

- Copied the Ubuntu ISO files to the Apache server
- All files have rx permissions (can download from a browser)

Anything else I should try?

Thanks

Comment: try to give proper read permissions for `/var/www/html` if you are using apache

Comment: did you find any solution for this, @Steve?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because it requires file that doesn't exist. 
Check Apache server access log to see which request returns 404.

In addition, try to install with this image file.(not the live version)
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.

Here are the Apache access logs, it looks like there is nothing abnormal. I tried with both the server and desktop images. https://imgur.com/a/F71b8ho